# Convert vim / search to search and replace without retyping regular expression

Tags: regex, vim, vi, replace

When I perform a search and replace in Vim, I like to use the search function (`/regex`) first to visually test my regex.

Is there a simple way to bring up the expression I wrote in a search and replace command without typing it again?

For example, if I wanted to find the word *perform* and replace it with *execute* in the above text, after doing:

`/perform`<kbd>enter</kbd>

is there a way to easily insert `perform` into the search and replace command below?

`:%s/perform/execute/g`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can type

```
/search_term
```

and then

```
:%s/<ctrl-r>// etc
```

where you actually press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then <kbd>/</kbd> to insert the search term.

Answer (score 20):

If you have done a previous search with :
`/foo`

You can simply type :
`:%s//bar/g`

and it will replace every occurrence of `foo` by `bar` because Vim understands implicitly you want to replace your previous search. You don't have to retype `foo` at all.

More generally to reuse a command from history you can use the command `q:` to bring up the command history and `q/` to bring up the search history in a small buffer. Once you're in there you can use every Vim command to paste, cut, recall a previous command by pressing `<Enter>`...

A great resource for your topic can be found there, this is a webcast about regexp and how to refine them using the command line window.
http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/

Comment: : I didn't know about that, great tip!  It doesn't seem to bring up your / searches however, just : commands.

Comment: Ah you're right, I hadn't noticed it only works for command and not search. For search you can use `q/` though

Comment: regarding your edit, that's awesome... if I could choose 2 answers as accepted, I would choose this as well :)

Comment: woah, nice. I've picked up some great tips from this :)

Answer (score 0):

%s/blah/blahh/cg won't help?

```
:%s/perform/execute/cg
```

Comment: `c` is nice but I like to highlight all the matches beforehand